# how to push docker-compose file to linux machine using azure devops

Tags: docker-compose, azure-devops

I have created my docker image and i was able to create build and release pipeline but I want to push all the front end backend services in one go using the docker-compose file using azure devops to a linux machine so i need help in achieving the same, can you guide me the steps, I am stuck on "how to push docker-compose file using azure devops"

I tried using docker compose task in build pipeline and tried using copy files and ssh task in the release pipeline but getting errors in terms of "failed to connect to vm using ssh connection details etc"

Comment: Okay, so you need to troubleshoot the SSH issue. If you want help with that, you'll need to provide more details on the exact error you're encountering.